Will a 2x8 shed floor with OSB support a small car?
I have a 16x20 shed/storage building.  I want to store a very small car (10ft long, 4.5ft wide, 1200lbs) on one side of the shed.
The shed sits on three 6x6 pressure treated 20 foot beams which each sit about 6 inches off the ground on blocks spaced at the four corners and also at the 10 foot mark of each beam. The blocks sit on concrete footings.
Above the runners are 2x8 joists spaced at 16" on center and a layer of Edgegold OSB on top of that.  I wanted to know if I would need to add another runner under the side the car will sit upon or perhaps add more blocks under the current runners to avoid any bending of the runners.
Calculating all this live load stuff seems confusing as all get out to me. The car doesn't seem that heavy to me to require much addition if any to the current flooring.

Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Are you going to be driving it in/out every day like a garage? Or are you going to drive it in once, work on it (or just store it) for a few months and then drive it out?

I'd worry about the OSB sagging over time as well.

I would hesitate to put a car on anything less than a serious warehouse floor, (inch-thick hardwood floors and joists designed for that load) or a real concrete slab. But I am not a construction engineer.
